# Is there a (concrete) category of superstructures?

Tags: set-theory, category-theory

The superstructure $V(X)$ over a set $X$ is usually defined as follows.

1. $V_0(X)$
2. $V_{i+1}(X) = V_i(X) \cup P(V_i(X))$
3. $V(X) = ⋃_{i=0}^∞V_i(X)$

This defines a metafunction $V.$

*Remark.* To make sure the $V$ is well-behaved, we should only apply it to sets $X$ consisting entirely of urelements. Otherwise, the structure of $V(X)$ may depend on more than just the cardinality of $X$.

Now intuitively, the domain of $V$ is the class of all abstract sets, and the codomain of $V$ is the class of all superstructures. Thus I'd like to know, is there a more structuralist definition of $V$? In particular, is there a concrete category of "superstructures" $\mathrm{Sus}$ such that $V : \mathrm{Set} \rightarrow \mathrm{Sus}$ can be defined as the left-adjoint to the forgetful functor $U : \mathrm{Sus} \rightarrow \mathrm{Set}$?

The idea is that the objects of $\mathrm{Sus}$ should be ordered pairs $(S,\in')$ where $\in'$ acts like a membership relation within the universe $S$.

Comment: No, $V$ is clearly not functorial as it is not bijection-invariant.

Comment: @ZhenLin, I understand what you're saying and it comes from an ambiguity in the question. I will clarify.

Comment: @ZhenLin, okay does the last sentence I just added address your concerns?

Comment: If you think about it for even one minute you will see that, depending on what $X$ is, $V_1 (X)$ may or may not be a _disjoint_ union of $X$ and $P (X)$. This means the isomorphism type of $V (X)$ depends on more than the cardinality of $X$.

Comment: @ZhenLin, yes that is usually viewed as a defect with the usual definition. The idea is to *avoid* that problem. I will add that to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have an endofunctor $T$ on a category $\mathcal{C}$ that you want to view as a left adjoint, it is necessary and sufficient to find natural transformations $\eta : \mathrm{id} \Rightarrow T$ and $\mu : T T \Rightarrow T$ such that $(T, \eta, \mu)$ is a monad; indeed, in that case, there exist a category $\mathcal{D}$ and an adjunction $F \dashv U : \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$ such that $T = U F$.

It is clear how to make this "superstructure" construction into an endofunctor $T$ on $\mathbf{Set}$, because each step of the construction is itself functorial. There is also an evident natural transformation $\eta : \mathrm{id} \Rightarrow T$. So we just have to find a suitable $\mu : T T \Rightarrow T$.

Unfortunately, the obvious thing only works if we replace $\mathscr{P}$ with $\mathscr{P}_{< \aleph_0}$: because then the rank of every element of $T T X$ will be finite (if we count elements of $X$ as having rank 0) and so can be "evaluated" to yield an element of $T X$. The category of $(T, \eta, \mu)$-algebras also admits a simpler description in this case: they are sets $A$ equipped with a map $\mathscr{P}_{< \aleph_0} A \to A$. You may think of this as the algebraic theory with one $n$-ary operation $\{ -, \ldots, - \}$ for each natural number $n$, subject to axioms of the form $\{ x, x \} = \{ x \}$, $\{ x, y \} = \{ y, x \}$, etc. The initial algebra is, of course, $V_\omega$, where structure map $\mathscr{P}_{< \aleph_0} V_\omega \to V_\omega$ is (literally!) the identity map.

The above can be generalised to $\mathscr{P}_{< \kappa}$ for any regular cardinal $\kappa$, but then one has to take $\kappa$-many steps in the transfinite construction of free algebras instead of just $\omega$-many.